Modeling of the "2 Body Problem" in OpenModelica
I'm trying to model the 2 Body Problem in OpenModelica (as a first step to model the 3 Body Problem) but I'm having some problems.
I'm using the LineForceWithMass object in order to have the force between the 2 objects on the line connecting the 2 but when i do it the position of the 2 bodies isn't update even if the force is computed in the correct way.
I realized a class "AttractionForce" that computes the force between the 2 bodies:
model AttractionForce
  
  import Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Interfaces;
  extends Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Interfaces.PartialCompliant;
  
  constant Real G = 6.67430e-11 "Gravitational constant";
  parameter SI.Mass m1;
  parameter SI.Mass m2;
  
  equation
  f = (G*m1*m2)/(s_rel^2);

annotation(
    Icon(graphics = {Polygon(origin = {10, 0}, lineColor = {255, 85, 0}, fillColor = {255, 85, 0}, fillPattern = FillPattern.Solid, points = {{-70, 20}, {-70, -20}, {30, -20}, {30, -40}, {70, 0}, {30, 40}, {30, 20}, {-70, 20}, {-70, 20}}), Polygon(origin = {-60, 0}, lineColor = {255, 85, 0}, fillColor = {255, 85, 0}, fillPattern = FillPattern.Solid, points = {{-20, 0}, {20, 40}, {20, -40}, {-20, 0}, {-20, 0}})}));

end AttractionForce;

Then I used this class with the LineForceWithMass object to model the gravitational attraction between the 2 bodies:
model GravitationalForce
  
  import Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Interfaces;
  import Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Forces;
  import Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Frames;
  extends Interfaces.PartialTwoFrames;
  
  parameter Boolean animation = true;
  parameter Boolean showMass = true;
  parameter SI.Distance s_small = 1e-10;
  parameter SI.Mass m1;
  parameter SI.Mass m2;
 
  Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Forces.LineForceWithMass lineForce(animateLine = animation, animateMass = showMass, fixedRotationAtFrame_a = true, fixedRotationAtFrame_b = true, m = 0, s_small = s_small) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}})));
 
  SI.Position r_rel_a[3] "Position vector from origin of frame_a to origin of frame_b, resolved in frame_a";
  Real e_a[3](each final unit = "1") "Unit vector on the line connecting the origin of frame_a with the origin of frame_b resolved in frame_a (directed from frame_a to frame_b)";
  SI.Force f "Line force acting on frame_a and on frame_b (positive, if acting on frame_b and directed from frame_a to frame_b)";
  SI.Distance length "Distance between the origin of frame_a and the origin of frame_b";
  SI.Position s "(Guarded) distance between the origin of frame_a and the origin of frame_b (>= s_small))";
  SI.Position r_rel_0[3] "Position vector from frame_a to frame_b resolved in world frame";
  Real e_rel_0[3](each final unit = "1") "Unit vector in direction from frame_a to frame_b, resolved in world frame";
 
  AttractionForce attractionForce( m1 = m1, m2 = m2)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {0, 44}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

equation
  r_rel_a = Frames.resolve2(frame_a.R, r_rel_0);
  e_a = r_rel_a/s;
  f = attractionForce.f;
  length = lineForce.length;
  s = lineForce.s;
  r_rel_0 = lineForce.frame_a.r_0 - lineForce.frame_b.r_0;
  e_rel_0 = r_rel_0/s;
 
  connect(frame_a, lineForce.frame_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-100, 0}, {-20, 0}}));
  connect(lineForce.frame_b, frame_b) annotation(
    Line(points = {{20, 0}, {100, 0}}, color = {95, 95, 95}));
  connect(lineForce.flange_a, attractionForce.flange_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-12, 20}, {-10, 20}, {-10, 44}}, color = {0, 127, 0}));
  connect(lineForce.flange_b, attractionForce.flange_b) annotation(
    Line(points = {{12, 20}, {10, 20}, {10, 44}}, color = {0, 127, 0}));


annotation(
    Icon(graphics = {Polygon(origin = {-50, 0}, lineColor = {0, 0, 255}, fillColor = {0, 0, 255}, fillPattern = FillPattern.Solid, points = {{-30, 0}, {-10, 40}, {-10, 20}, {28, 20}, {30, 20}, {30, -20}, {-10, -20}, {-10, -40}, {-30, 0}, {-30, 0}}), Polygon(origin = {50, 0}, lineColor = {0, 0, 255}, fillColor = {0, 0, 255}, fillPattern = FillPattern.Solid, points = {{-30, 20}, {-30, -18}, {-30, -20}, {10, -20}, {10, -40}, {30, 0}, {10, 40}, {10, 20}, {8, 20}, {-30, 20}})}));
end GravitationalForce;

Then i just put everything togheter to simulate the problem but it doesn't work and i can't manage to understand why (it's one of my first times using OpenModelica so I don't know if there's something obvious that I'm overlooking).
model TwoBodyProblem
  
  import Modelica.Math.Vectors.norm;
  import Modelica.SIunits;
  
  parameter SI.Mass m1 = 1e24 "Mass of first body";
  parameter SI.Mass m2 = 1e24 "Mass of second body";
  
  inner Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.World world(animateGravity = true, axisDiameter = 1e8, axisLength = 1e9, gravitySphereDiameter = 0.1, gravityType = 
   Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Types.GravityTypes.NoGravity, mu = 0) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {16, -54}, extent = {{-80, -20}, {-60, 0}}, rotation = 0)));
 
  Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.Body planet1(I_11 = 0.1, I_22 = 0.1, I_33 = 0.1, m = m1, r_0(start = {1e10, 0, 0}), r_CM = {0, 0, 0}, sphereDiameter = 1e9)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-60, 40}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));
  Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.Body planet2(I_11 = 0.1, I_22 = 0.1, I_33 = 0.1, m = m2, r_0(start = {0, 1e10, 0}), r_CM = {0, 0, 0}, sphereDiameter = 1e9)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {36, 40}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
 GravitationalForce gravitationalForce(m1 = m1, m2 = m2) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-14, 40}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
equation
  connect(planet2.frame_a, gravitationalForce.frame_b) annotation(
    Line(points = {{26, 40}, {-4, 40}}, color = {95, 95, 95}));
 connect(planet1.frame_a, gravitationalForce.frame_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-50, 40}, {-24, 40}}, color = {95, 95, 95}));
  annotation(
    Icon(graphics = {Ellipse(origin = {-43, 38}, lineColor = {170, 85, 255}, fillColor = {170, 85, 255}, fillPattern = FillPattern.Solid, extent = {{-27, 28}, {27, -28}}), Ellipse(origin = {54, -55}, lineColor = {85, 255, 0}, fillColor = {0, 255, 0}, fillPattern = FillPattern.Solid, extent = {{-34, 35}, {34, -35}}), Ellipse(origin = {7, -12}, extent = {{-71, 68}, {71, -68}})}));
end TwoBodyProblem;


What exactly does not work? Did you read the error messages? Every class should pass the check before you use it somewhere else. AttractionForce and GravitationalForce are missing the import statement for the SI package.  TwoBodyProblem imports SIunits, which indicates MSL 3.x, but uses SI, which is MSL 4.0.0 style.

The fact is that it does compile and simulate but the simulation doesn't work and everything stays still. Every class passes the check.

I think not. The code you posted cannot work without fixing the import problems. However, after fixing that I see what you mean.

I think it didn't show an error because these classes are defined in a package where i already imported the SI library

There are a number of issues:

You need to start with velocity orthogonal to the direction between the two masses, because otherwise they will just accelerate towards each other and collide (physically and numerically bad). That might not be needed in a n-body problem with n>2, since the initial positions avoid that unless all the bodies are on a line or highly symmetrical.
You need a stricter tolerance and likely more output points. General integrators are not ideal for preserving energy in Hamiltonian systems.
The system isn't centered around the origin - which makes it hard to understand.
I'm not sure if lineforce is a good abstraction here.

So correct it to something like:
Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.Body planet1(I_11 = 0.1, I_22 = 0.1, I_33 = 0.1, m = m1, r_0(start = {5e9, -5e9, 0}),
r_CM={0,0,0},
v_0(start={1e2,0,0}),                                                                                                               sphereDiameter = 1e9)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-60, 40}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));
Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.Body planet2(I_11 = 0.1, I_22 = 0.1, I_33 = 0.1, m = m2, r_0(start = -m1/m2*{5e9, -5e9, 0}),
r_CM={0,0,0},
v_0(start=-m1/m2*{1e2,0,0}),                                                                                                                sphereDiameter = 1e9)  annotation(
 Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {36, 40}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
Real rcm[3]=(planet1.r_0*m1+planet2.r_0*m2)/(m1+m2);

And simulate to 1e9 s, and tolerance 1e-8.
The rcm is the center of mass coordinates, which should stay close to zero.
Additionally, instead of setting the inertia to a small number you can use Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.PointMass
